# How to compute the integral $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\cdot\exp\bigg({\frac{-a}{2t}-bt}\bigg)dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to get the following for $a,b>0$? $$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\cdot\exp\bigg({\frac{-a}{2t}-bt}\bigg)dt=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2b}}\cdot \exp\big(-\sqrt{2ab}\big) $$

The context for this identity is its use in computing the resolvent of Brownian motion in the stochastic calculus book by Le Gall (screenshot below).  I figured there had to be an elementary way to compute it, i.e. without using the fact Le Gall alludes to about the Laplace transform of the hitting time of Brownian motion. As is indicated in the comments, this is clearly a duplicate so I wouldn't object to its being closed for **that** reason.  Although maybe those who posted the excellent answers below should've been given the chance to migrate their answers to the post of which this is a duplicate, if they wish. [image]

Comment: A definite integral from $0$ to $\infty$ of an ugly mess always makes me think of contour integration right away.  Do you know complex calculus?

Comment: @RobertTheTutor yes, thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp(-ax^2-\frac b{x^2})\,dx$ for $a,b&gt;0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496088/how-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-exp-ax2-frac-bx2-dx-for-a-b0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substitute $s^2=t$

$$I = \int_0^\infty \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-b\left[s^2+\frac{a}{2bs^2}\right]\right)ds = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-b\left[s^2+\frac{a}{2bs^2}\right]\right)ds$$

by even symmetry. Then complete the square on the term in the exponential

$$s^2 + \frac{a}{2bs^2} = \left[s-\sqrt{\frac{a}{2b}}\frac{1}{s}\right]^2 + \sqrt{\frac{2a}{b}}$$

which gives us the new integral

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\sqrt{2ab}\right)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-b\left[s-\sqrt{\frac{a}{2b}}\frac{1}{s}\right]^2\right)ds$$

Then use the following theorem (in this form attributed to Glasser's Master Theorem, but known to Cauchy)

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\left(x-\frac{k}{x}\right)dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$$

for $k>0$. Thus the integral simplifies to

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\sqrt{2ab}\right)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-bs^2\right)ds = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2b}}\exp\left(-\sqrt{2ab}\right)$$

using the Gaussian integral result.

Comment: This is a correct answer, a nice application of Glasser's rule. See 2.3.16.3 of "Integrals and Series, Vol. 1: Elementary Functions, Prudnikov, Brychkov, Marichev."

Comment: Wow, that is a great trick. I need to remember that.  Glasser.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor I was just as fascinated by the theorem when I saw it for the first time :) I use it all the time on integration bee problems I write.

Comment: So simple .... after reading a good answer !

Answer (score 2):

The following change of variables

$$u=\sqrt{t},\qquad t=u^2,\qquad dt =2udu$$

gives
\begin{align*}
I:&= \int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\cdot\exp\bigg({\frac{-a}{2t}-bt}\bigg)dt\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int^\infty_0\frac{1}{u} e^{-\frac{a}{u^2}-b u^2}2udu=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int^\infty_0 e^{-\frac{a}{u^2}-b u^2}\,du=F(a)
\end{align*}

The method used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3696598/using-differentiation-under-integral-sign-prove-int-0-infty-e-x2-fr?rq=1) can be then applied to estimate the integral $I$. Here is more or less what we get when we carry out that aforementioned method:

$$F'(a)=-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int^\infty_0 e^{-\big(\frac{a}{u^2}+ bu^2\big)}\frac{1}{u^2}\,du 
$$
The change of variables
$$v=\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b} u},\qquad u=\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b} v},\qquad du=-\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}v^2}$$
leads to
$$F'(a)=-\sqrt{\frac{2a}{b\pi}}\int^\infty_0  e^{-\Big(bv^2 +\frac{a}{v^2}\Big)}\frac{b}{a}\,dv=-\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}F(a)$$

The first order ODE we get satisfies the following initial condition:
$$F(0)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int^\infty_0e^{-bu^2}\,du=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2b}}$$
Hence
$$
F'(a)+\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}F(a)=0
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
e^{2\sqrt{ba}}\Big(F'(a)+\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}F(a)\Big)=\frac{d}{da}\Big(e^{2\sqrt{ba}}F(a)\Big)=0
$$
and so
$$
e^{2\sqrt{ab}}F(a)-F(0)=e^{2\sqrt{ab}}F(a)-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2b}}=0
$$