# calculate :$\int_0^\infty\ e^{-a^2(y^2+\frac{p^2}{4a^2y^2})}\,dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Trying to calculate $$\int_0^\infty\ e^{-a^2(y^2+\frac{p^2}{4a^2y^2})}dy.$$ When I searched it on Google, I found the formula $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \ e^{-a(x+b)^{2}}dx=\sqrt\frac{\pi}{a},$$
but when I apply the aforementioned formula I got $\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2a}{e^{pa}}$, but the answer in my book is $\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2a}{e^{-pa}}$. Can I get help?

Comment: Write x^{2y} to get $x^{2y}$. If you just use x^2y, you end up with $x^2y$. So put everything in a curly bracket that goes into the power.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I am not sure about your edits. Shouldn't it be for example $e^{-a(x+b)^2}$?

Comment: @Gary Thank you and sorry about the mistake!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think in the first expression, the OP wanted some of the objects in the exponent as well, otherwise $e^{-a^2}$ is just a constant and the integral diverges (if it is taken with respect to $y$). I gave the MathJax help to the OP so that they can fix it themselves.

Comment: @umar See if we edited your question correctly.

Comment: This is a nice textbook application of Glasser Master theorem, but you can also prove the result by symmetry and using $y\leftrightarrow\frac{1}{y}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using differentiation under integral sign, prove $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(x^2+\frac {a^2}{x^2})b^2} dx=\frac {\sqrt {\pi}}{2b} \cdot e^{-2ab^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3696598/using-differentiation-under-integral-sign-prove-int-0-infty-e-x2-fr) (found using the formula searching tool https://approach0.xyz/search/)

Comment: @Ninad Munshi Thanks for the reference to [Glasser Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem) I didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

$I=\int_0^\infty e^{-a^2(y^2+\frac{p^2}{4a^2y^2})}dy$
$＝\int_0^\infty e^{-a^2[(y-\frac{p}{2ay})^2]-pa}dy$
$=e^{-pa}\int_0^\infty e^{-a^2(y-\frac{p}{2ay})}dy$

let  $y-\frac{p}{2ay}=s$,then $y=\frac{1}{4a}\Big(2as+\sqrt{(2as)^2+8ap}\Big)$

then  $dy=\frac{1}{4a}\Big(2a+\frac{2as}{\sqrt{(2as)^2+8ap}}\Big)ds$

$I=e^{-pa}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a^2s^2}\frac{1}{4a}\Big(2a+\frac{2as}{\sqrt{(2as)^2+8ap}}\Big)ds=\frac{e^{-pa}}{4}\Big(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a^2s^2}dy +\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{2as e^{-a^2s^2}}{\sqrt{(2as)^2+8ap}}dy\Big)
$

$=\frac{1}{4}e^{-pa}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a^2s^2}dy=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2a}e^{-pa}$